# Using ASUS USB-AC53 Dual-Band Adapter with raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, wireless, openelec, wireless-adapter

I have a asus ac53 dual-band adapter. I was originally using it with a windows laptop but I am curious if I can use it with my raspberry pi set up with open elec. I know the cd that came with it is only supported by windows, but I have heard that people have used it with different versions of linux before. If not open elec maybe another os, such as raspbian.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various sources claim the chipset in this is a Broadcom BCM43526.  There is a driver for BCM43xx chips in the linux kernel included with raspbian, the `b43` module.  Looking at notes in the source, however, the specific USB id for this one is not mentioned, so it may not work and even more likely, won't be recognized.

So you could try connecting it, then check `lsmod | grep b43`.  If it is not loaded, `modprobe b43`.  Then check `ip link` and see if you have a `wlan0`.

If not, you are probably out of luck.  The only report I found of someone confirming they got this device to work on linux used [NDISwrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDISwrapper), which makes use of Windows XP drivers (there's probably one on the CD).  However, this only works on normal PC architecture (x86/x86-64), so there is no chance of using it on the pi.